# Removing row if number of NA's is larger than 2 (or any number) in a certain amount of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the following panel data frame:

```
         X1     X2     X3     X4     X5    Y1     Y2     Y3     Y4     Y5
Ind 1    7      NA     NA     NA     NA     1      4      6      8      6 
Ind 2    2      NA     16     NA     NA     5     16     12      3      4
Ind 3    NA     NA      NA    19     92    13     NA     12     NA     NA
Ind 4    32     5       12    3       5    NA     NA     NA     NA      4
Ind 5    44      3      46    3      47     3      2     NA      3      4
Ind 6    NA     34      NA    8      NA    14     15     12      3      4
Ind 7    49     55      67    49     89     6     17      2      3      4
Ind 8    NA     NA      49    NA     NA    11     20      6      NA     4
Ind 9    1      1        5    NA     9     NA     NA     NA      NA     NA
```

In pastable format:

```
df <- read.table(text="Index_name,X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 Y1 Y2     Y3     Y4     Y5
Ind_1    7      NA     NA     NA     NA     1      4      6      8      6 
Ind_2    2      NA     16     NA     NA     5     16     12      3      4
Ind_3    NA     NA      NA    19     92    13     NA     12     NA     NA
Ind_4    32     5       12    3       5    NA     NA     NA     NA      4
Ind_5    44      3      46    3      47     3      2     NA      3      4
Ind_6    NA     34      NA    8      NA    14     15     12      3      4
Ind_7    49     55      67    49     89     6     17      2      3      4
Ind_8    NA     NA      49    NA     NA    11     20      6      NA     4
Ind_9    1      1        5    NA     9     NA     NA     NA      NA     NA",row.names=1,
                 header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I want to filter out all rows that don't have at least 2 non-`NA` values in *both* the columns that start with `X` and the columns that start with `Y`.

For example:

- Ind1: Drop (only 1 value in X1-X5)
- Ind2: Keep (cause here there are at least 2 numbers in X)
- Ind3: Keep cause both X and Y have 2 or more observations.
- Ind4: Delete (only 1 value in Y1-Y5)
- Ind5: Keep
- Ind6: Keep
- Ind7: Keep
- Ind8: Delete (Only 1 value in X1-X5)
- Ind9: Delete (though X is ok, Y is not okay.)

Comment: Can you run `dput(your_df)` on your data frame and paste the output here? It will make it easier for contributors to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this. Basically, you are counting (with `rowSums`), the number of non-NA data points first in x1-x5 and then in y1-y5. To indentify non-NAs, I use `!is.na()`. The `!` is a negation, so the expression means "Not an NA". Finally, you are keeping only the rows where "row sum of non-NAs is >=2" for x1-x5 AND (`&`) for y1-y5. To be clear about the indexing, there are 10 columns in your `data.frame`. `df[,1:5]` represents the first 5 columns, which are x1-x5.

```
df[rowSums(!is.na(df[,1:5]))>=2 & rowSums(!is.na(df[,6:10]))>=2,]

      X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5
Ind_2  2 NA 16 NA NA  5 16 12  3  4
Ind_3 NA NA NA 19 92 13 NA 12 NA NA
Ind_5 44  3 46  3 47  3  2 NA  3  4
Ind_6 NA 34 NA  8 NA 14 15 12  3  4
Ind_7 49 55 67 49 89  6 17  2  3  4
```

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text="Index_name,X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 Y1 Y2     Y3     Y4     Y5
Ind_1    7      NA     NA     NA     NA     1      4      6      8      6 
Ind_2    2      NA     16     NA     NA     5     16     12      3      4
Ind_3    NA     NA      NA    19     92    13     NA     12     NA     NA
Ind_4    32     5       12    3       5    NA     NA     NA     NA      4
Ind_5    44      3      46    3      47     3      2     NA      3      4
Ind_6    NA     34      NA    8      NA    14     15     12      3      4
Ind_7    49     55      67    49     89     6     17      2      3      4
Ind_8    NA     NA      49    NA     NA    11     20      6      NA     4
Ind_9    1      1        5    NA     9     NA     NA     NA      NA     NA",row.names=1,
                 header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```